# Possible SSD failure?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure

I have a Lenovo x220i notebook computer which came with a 320 GB HDD. A few months ago, I purchased an Intel 80 GB mSATA SSD and installed that myself. I made the SSD my boot drive and I mapped the 320 HDD as a D drive. This has worked great for the past few months until tonight, the computer just suddenly failed. The screen went black without warning. Now when I try to boot, the hard drive light flashes briefly and within 2 seconds the computer fails with no audible sound given.

Is it reasonable to guess that my mSATA SSD is what has failed me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the drive failed, there would be a some kind of disk error displayed on the screen.